# Error in security config Symfony - unsupported keys for "_security_logout":"firewall"

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create Symfony login page.

I am a beginner student of Symfony, I am learning this framework since month by using Symfony documentation, I followed the documentation about user verification, but I have this error.

> The routing file "C:\Users\wuwus\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Symfony
> projekty\blog\config/routes/security.yaml" contains unsupported keys
> for "_security_logout": "firewalls". Expected one of: "resource",
> "type", "prefix", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults",
> "requirements", "options", "condition", "controller", "name_prefix",
> "trailing_slash_on_root", "locale", "format", "utf8", "exclude",
> "stateless" in C:\Users\wuwus\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Symfony
> projekty\blog\config/routes/security.yaml (which is being imported
> from "C:\Users\wuwus\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Symfony
> projekty\blog\src\Kernel.php").

I have this error every time I try to paste this code to
`security.yaml` :

```
_security_logout:
    resource: security.route_loader.logout
    type: service

    firewalls:
        main:
            # ...
            form_login:
                # "app_login" is the name of the route created previously
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                enable_csrf: true`
```

This error is happening when I add firewalls at the bottom of the code. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Can you edit and post your full security.yaml file..

Comment: i pasted picture

Comment: Do you have the same Symfony version of the documentation ?

Comment: Yes , symfony 7 im sure

Comment: *_security_logout* is not correct, it should be just *security*. Like the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) show is how it should be laid out. That's what the error is saying.